# D3 limit update selection to entries with actual changes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to display data I'm receiving via websockets as a simple html table. This works fine so far.
Now I need to visualize changes to that data, so I would like to use transitions with background-color or something to visually highlight the changed cells.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var data = new d3.map({"In1": false, "Reg1": 0815});

data.set("In2", true);
data.set("Reg2", 4711);

var table = d3.select("#foo").append("table").attr("class", "table table-bordered table-striped");

var thead = table.append("thead");
thead.append("th").text("Test");

var tbody = table.append("tbody");

update(data.entries());
```

When I receive new data via websockets, I simply update the data map via data.set(key,value) and call the update function:

```
function update(data) {
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data);

    rows.exit().remove();
    rows.enter().append("tr");

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function (row) {
            return [row.key, row.value];
        });

    cells.enter().append("td");

    cells.text(function (d) { return d; });
    cells.transition().style('color', 'red').transition().style('color', 'green');
}
```

The problem is that the update selection seems to apply to ALL elements, not only to those whose values actually changed (that is what I hoped it would be).
Is this something I'm just doing wrong, or is this generally the case? If so, how could I apply the transitions only to the actually changed elements?

edit: Created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phfmz16o/), you'll see that all table cells are animated, I only want the value-cell of "Reg2" to be....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3 doesn't offer anything out of the box for this, but one approach is to store the old data with the element and then, on update, compare the new to the old to see if it has changed. This way, you can filter your elements and apply the transition only to the ones where the data has changed:

```
cells.filter(function() { return this.__olddata__ != this.__data__; })
        .each(function() { this.__olddata__ = this.__data__; })
        .transition().style('color', 'red').transition().style('color', 'green');
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/phfmz16o/2/).

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks, works fine and is pretty straight forward! I had thought of somethng similar, but couldn't get it done. I'm really suprised that there's nothing out of the box for this. Couldn't it be quite some performance advantage when only updating affected dom elements?

Comment: I suspect that this is something that browsers themselves would optimise -- setting an attribute value to the same as it already is may get optimised away.

Comment: You're probably right, and I'm pretty sure Mike did spend a minute or two with this idea already. However, it wouldn't hurt if we had another virtual selection called "changed" or something that we could use for this...

Comment: This would actually require additional memory (to store the old data) and processing time (to do the comparison). In general, it would slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `cells` is the result of the `selectAll`, which by definition is the full selection. You want to apply the transition to the `enter` selection instead, which is the result of the `cells.enter()` call. Because of `D3`'s method chaining, that is still what you get returned from the `append` that you call on it. However, once you call `cells.text`, you are re-using the original selection. Either you call `transition` chained to the `append` call, or you store the result of the `enter` in another variable and use that for the transition.

Comment: This would not work, because the OP interested in addressing DOM elements that already exist and have data but whose data was updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bumpanck, but meetamit is right, that won't work as desired....